# Ansible - parse a list of nested dictionaries to create a new list

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible, json-query

I have the following list of dictionaries

```
"tor_vlan_list": [
    {
        "switch_01": {
            "Vlan1": {
                "id": "1",
                "ip": "unassigned",
                "ok": "NO",
                "protocol": "down",
                "status": "up"
            },
            "Vlan10": {
                "id": "10",
                "ip": "10.10.10.2/24",
                "ok": "YES",
                "protocol": "up",
                "status": "up"
            },
            "Vlan20": {
                "id": "20",
                "ip": "10.10.20.2/24",
                "ok": "YES",
                "protocol": "up",
                "status": "up"
            },
            "Vlan30": {
                "id": "30",
                "ip": "10.10.30.2/24",
                "ok": "YES",
                "protocol": "up",
                "status": "up"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "switch_02": {
            "Vlan1": {
                "id": "1",
                "ip": "unassigned",
                "ok": "NO",
                "protocol": "down",
                "status": "up"
            },
            "Vlan10": {
                "id": "10",
                "ip": "10.10.10.3/24",
                "ok": "YES",
                "protocol": "up",
                "status": "up"
            },
            "Vlan20": {
                "id": "20",
                "ip": "10.10.20.3/24",
                "ok": "YES",
                "protocol": "up",
                "status": "up"
            },
            "Vlan30": {
                "id": "30",
                "ip": "10.10.30.3/24",
                "ok": "YES",
                "protocol": "up",
                "status": "up"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

from this, i need to extract the list of vlan IDs for each switch and store these as follows

```
"new_list": [
    { 
     "switch_01": [1,10,20,30]
    },
    {
     "switch_02": [1,10,20,30]
    }
]
```

I would like to pass the list values as a var in the command *show vlan {{item}}"

I've tried getting the needed detail using combinations of selectattr, map, combine, json_query, etc to set a new ansible fact but, all have eluded me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below expressions

```yaml
  new_list_keys: "{{ tor_vlan_list|json_query('[].keys(@)') }}"
  new_list_vals: "{{ tor_vlan_list|json_query('[].*.*.id') }}"
  new_list: |
    [{% for i in new_list_keys|zip(new_list_vals) %}
    {{ dict(i.0|zip(i.1|map('map', 'int'))) }},
    {% endfor %}]
```

give what you want

```yaml
  new_list:
    - switch_01: [1, 10, 20, 30]
    - switch_02: [1, 10, 20, 30]
```

```yaml
  new_list_keys:
    - [switch_01]
    - [switch_02]

  new_list_vals:
    - - ['1', '10', '20', '30']
    - - ['1', '10', '20', '30']
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    tor_vlan_list:
    - switch_01:
        Vlan1: {id: '1', ip: unassigned, ok: 'NO', protocol: down, status: up}
        Vlan10: {id: '10', ip: 10.10.10.2/24, ok: 'YES', protocol: up, status: up}
        Vlan20: {id: '20', ip: 10.10.20.2/24, ok: 'YES', protocol: up, status: up}
        Vlan30: {id: '30', ip: 10.10.30.2/24, ok: 'YES', protocol: up, status: up}
    - switch_02:
        Vlan1: {id: '1', ip: unassigned, ok: 'NO', protocol: down, status: up}
        Vlan10: {id: '10', ip: 10.10.10.3/24, ok: 'YES', protocol: up, status: up}
        Vlan20: {id: '20', ip: 10.10.20.3/24, ok: 'YES', protocol: up, status: up}
        Vlan30: {id: '30', ip: 10.10.30.3/24, ok: 'YES', protocol: up, status: up}

    new_list_keys: "{{ tor_vlan_list|json_query('[].keys(@)') }}"
    new_list_vals: "{{ tor_vlan_list|json_query('[].*.*.id') }}"
    new_list: |
      [{% for i in new_list_keys|zip(new_list_vals) %}
      {{ dict(i.0|zip(i.1|map('map', 'int'))) }},
      {% endfor %}]

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: new_list_keys|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: new_list_vals|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: new_list|type_debug
    - debug:
        var: new_list|to_yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

Ansible isn't great at manipulating data structures, but you could do something like this:

```
- set_fact:
    new_list: >
      {{
        new_list + [
          {
            switch[0]: switch[1].values()|list|map(attribute='id')|map('int')
          }
        ]
      }}
  vars:
    new_list: []
    switch: "{{ item.items()|first|list }}"
  loop: "{{ tor_vlan_list }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ switch[0] }}"

- debug:
    var: new_list
```

This makes somewhat complicated use of `set_fact` in a loop. Given your example input, the `debug` task prints your desired data structure:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "new_list": [
        {
            "switch_01": [
                1,
                10,
                20,
                30
            ]
        },
        {
            "switch_02": [
                1,
                10,
                20,
                30
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Alternately, you could place your logic into a custom filter in `filter_plugins/switches.py`, like this:

```
def transform_vlan_list(vlan_list):
    return [
        {switch[0]: [int(vlan["id"]) for vlan in switch[1].values()]}
        for x in vlan_list
        for switch in x.items()
    ]


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {"transform_vlan_list": transform_vlan_list}
```

The advantage here is that you've moved your logic into Python, which is much better at *manipulating* data.

With this custom filter plugin, you can produce the same output as the first example like this:

```
- set_fact:
    new_list: "{{ tor_vlan_list | transform_vlan_list }}"

- debug:
    var: new_list
```