# Ansible - Nested Loop with list of dictionaries when dictionary values are lists

Tags: list, loops, ansible, nested-loops

I have a list of dictionaries.

- Dictionary keys are Cisco Switch names
- Dictionary values are vlan IDs that are configured on the corresponding switch

```json
"switch_vlan_ids": [
    {
        "switch01": ["1", "10", "30", "50"]
    },
    {
        "switch02": ["1", "20", "40", "60"]
    }
]
```

I'm attempting to loop through each switch and, on each switch, loop through each *ID* so that I can pass this ID to a command, eg `show vlan {{id}}`

The end goal, connect to a bunch of switches, verify that for each switch that the switch ports are configured for each vlan ID and, report an error/fail if not.

I tried a nested loop but, the inner loop complains that the outer loop loop_var isn't defined

```yaml
 - name: Outer loop - Iterate through TOR Switches
   ansible.builtin.debug:
     msg: "TOR Name: {{ tor_item.key }}"
   loop: "{{ switch_vlan_ids | map('dict2items') | flatten }}"
   loop_control:
     loop_var: tor_item

 - name: Inner loop - Iterate through VLAN IDs
   ansible.builtin.debug:
     msg: "VLAN ID: {{ id_item.value }}"
   loop: "{{ tor_item.value }}"
   loop_control:
     loop_var: id_item
```

I've also attempted to just loop through the ID values but, this doesn't give the switch name so, if there's an error, I can't report the name of the switch with the error

```yaml
- name: Set fact to loop through the tor_vlan_is_list values
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    switch_vlan_id_values: "{{ switch_vlan_ids | json_query('[].values(@)') | flatten }}"
- debug: var=switch_vlan_id_list_values
```

the above returns

```yaml
"switch_vlan_id_values": ["1", "10", "30", "50", "1", "20", "40", "60"]
```

I've even tried a Jinja filter like below but abandoned it as I have no idea how I'd pass the values to an API call

```yaml
- name: blah
  set_fact: | 
    {% for switch in switch_vlan_ids %}
    {% for name,ids in switch.items() %}
    {% for id in ids %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"Loop through each switch and, on each switch, loop through each ID."***

A: Adding `subelements('value')` to the pipe does the job

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ switch_vlan_ids|map('dict2items')|flatten|subelements('value') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: switch01 1
  msg: switch01 10
  msg: switch01 30
  msg: switch01 50
  msg: switch02 1
  msg: switch02 20
  msg: switch02 40
  msg: switch02 60
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    switch_vlan_ids:
      - switch01: ["1", "10", "30", "50"]
      - switch02: ["1", "20", "40", "60"]

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ switch_vlan_ids|map('dict2items')|flatten|subelements('value') }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following self explanatory playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    "switch_vlan_ids": [
      {
        "switch01": [ "1", "10", "30", "50" ]
      },
      {
        "switch02": [ "1", "20", "40", "60" ]
      }
    ]

    switch_vlan_ids_dict: "{{ switch_vlan_ids | combine }}"
    switch_vlan_ids_list: "{{ switch_vlan_ids_dict | dict2items(key_name='switch', value_name='vlan_ids') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Show original var
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: switch_vlan_ids
        
    - name: Transform var to an easier to manage dict
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: switch_vlan_ids_dict

    - name: Transform the dict to an easy to parse list
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: switch_vlan_ids_list

    - name: Loop through the list with subelements
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg:
          - Switch is {{ item.0.switch }}
          - Vlan id is {{ item.1 }}
      loop: "{{ lookup('subelements', switch_vlan_ids_list, 'vlan_ids') }}"
```

gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show original var] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "switch_vlan_ids": [
        {
            "switch01": [
                "1",
                "10",
                "30",
                "50"
            ]
        },
        {
            "switch02": [
                "1",
                "20",
                "40",
                "60"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Transform var to an easier to manage dict] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "switch_vlan_ids_dict": {
        "switch01": [
            "1",
            "10",
            "30",
            "50"
        ],
        "switch02": [
            "1",
            "20",
            "40",
            "60"
        ]
    }
}

TASK [Transform the dict to an easy to parse list] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "switch_vlan_ids_list": [
        {
            "switch": "switch01",
            "vlan_ids": [
                "1",
                "10",
                "30",
                "50"
            ]
        },
        {
            "switch": "switch02",
            "vlan_ids": [
                "1",
                "20",
                "40",
                "60"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Loop through the list with subelements] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'switch': 'switch01'}, '1']) => {
    "msg": [
        "Switch is switch01",
        "Vlan id is 1"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'switch': 'switch01'}, '10']) => {
    "msg": [
        "Switch is switch01",
        "Vlan id is 10"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'switch': 'switch01'}, '30']) => {
    "msg": [
        "Switch is switch01",
        "Vlan id is 30"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'switch': 'switch01'}, '50']) => {
    "msg": [
        "Switch is switch01",
        "Vlan id is 50"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'switch': 'switch02'}, '1']) => {
    "msg": [
        "Switch is switch02",
        "Vlan id is 1"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'switch': 'switch02'}, '20']) => {
    "msg": [
        "Switch is switch02",
        "Vlan id is 20"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'switch': 'switch02'}, '40']) => {
    "msg": [
        "Switch is switch02",
        "Vlan id is 40"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'switch': 'switch02'}, '60']) => {
    "msg": [
        "Switch is switch02",
        "Vlan id is 60"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Why `"{{ lookup('subelements', switch_vlan_ids_list, 'vlan_ids') }}"` instead of `{{ switch_vlan_ids_list|subelements('vlan_ids') }}`? Is there an advantage to using the lookup vs the filter?

Comment: @larsk not that I know of at this point. Simple habit. If I really had to justify, I'd argue that the old but still valid `with_subelements` is calling the lookup in the background. Both are entirely valid though and probably have very similar performance (although I admit I was too lazy to test)

Answer (score 1):

Restructure your data so that instead of:

```
"switch_vlan_ids": [
    {
        "switch01": ["1", "10", "30", "50"]
    },
    {
        "switch02": ["1", "20", "40", "60"]
    }
]
```

You have instead:

```
"switch_vlan_ids": [
    {
        "name": "switch01",
        "vlans": ["1", "10", "30", "50"]
    },
    {
        "name": "switch02",
        "vlans": ["1", "20", "40", "60"]
    }
]
```

Now we can use the [`subelements`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html) filter to achieve the effect of a nested loop. If we modify [yesterday's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77916683/147356) so that instead we have:

```
def transform_vlan_list(vlan_list):
    return [
        {
            "name": switch[0],
            "vlans": [int(vlan["id"]) for vlan in switch[1].values()],
        }
        for x in vlan_list
        for switch in x.items()
    ]


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {"transform_vlan_list": transform_vlan_list}
```

Then we can write a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - vlans.json
  tasks:
    - loop: "{{ tor_vlan_list | transform_vlan_list | subelements('vlans') }}"
      debug:
        msg:
          - switch: "{{ item.0.name }}"
          - vlan id: "{{ item.1 }}"
```

And get the output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'switch_01', 'vlans': [1, 10, 30, 50]}, 1]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "switch": "switch_01"
        },
        {
            "vlan id": "1"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'switch_01', 'vlans': [1, 10, 30, 50]}, 10]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "switch": "switch_01"
        },
        {
            "vlan id": "10"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'switch_01', 'vlans': [1, 10, 30, 50]}, 30]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "switch": "switch_01"
        },
        {
            "vlan id": "30"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'switch_01', 'vlans': [1, 10, 30, 50]}, 50]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "switch": "switch_01"
        },
        {
            "vlan id": "50"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'switch_02', 'vlans': [1, 20, 40, 60]}, 1]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "switch": "switch_02"
        },
        {
            "vlan id": "1"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'switch_02', 'vlans': [1, 20, 40, 60]}, 20]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "switch": "switch_02"
        },
        {
            "vlan id": "20"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'switch_02', 'vlans': [1, 20, 40, 60]}, 40]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "switch": "switch_02"
        },
        {
            "vlan id": "40"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'switch_02', 'vlans': [1, 20, 40, 60]}, 60]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "switch": "switch_02"
        },
        {
            "vlan id": "60"
        }
    ]
}
```